# Shutdown-on-LAN capability

Tags: power-supply, power, network-adapter, wake-on-lan

There is a technology, called WOL.

Is the an opposite? Is it possible to shutdown a computer via LAN?

I would expect small embedded linux in a NIC which was capable to long-press power off button.

The goal is to cold reboot remote computer if it is hanged.

Comment: You can cold reboot a virtual machine by telling the hypervisor to do so. If your computer hangs because of software and you can make a VM from it, this may be a reasonable approach.

Answer (score 3):

Intel AMT can do that.

It's based on an additional Intel ME coprocessor built into Intel chipsets. Not all motherboards have remote control features, though, only those equipped with additional Intel AMT chip.

Once AMT is enabled, a control panel is available at port 16992, which provides, among others, power management options. There are three or four options available when the system is on:

- Turn power off
- Cycle power off and on
- Reset
- Graceful shutdown (available only in Windows)

[image: A screenshot from Intel AMT web panel showing Remote Control page with mentioned options visible.]

The panel is also available when system is off and allows for booting it remotely in a manner similar to WOL.

Note that enabling AMT can possibly be a security risk, as it provides advanced system management options for anyone in local network who knows your credentials (configured separately from OS user accounts).

Comment: Nearly all servers come with a BMC (indeed a small embedded linux) which has this feature (Dell iDRAC, HP iLO, etc.), although I believe it's not usually embedded in the CPU unlike AMT.

Comment: Thanks. Is it belong to processor, motherboard, chipset or what? How to know if I have it? How to know what to buy to have it?

Comment: Strictly speaking, Intel ME which is required for this feature is embedded in all Intel chipsets, but Intel AMT is available as a separate feature on some motherboards. @Dims look for Intel vPro, it's a marketing name for a group of professional-oriented technologies by Intel. If you want a laptop, look at the business series like Dell Latitude.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the "technology" is called "[Intelligent Platform Management Interface (IPMI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_Platform_Management_Interface)". IPMI is an autonomous subsystem and provides power management and monitoring including the option to turn of the power on a frozen system (since it works independently from the "rest" of the host system). It's usually integrated on the main board an can be usually accessed through the "LAN"/Ethernet port (for example on the E3C226D2I ASRock mainboard although this one has a second dedicated IPMI Ethernet port).

You can update an existing system without "IPMI on board" for example with a "IPMI PCI card" e.g. the [Aten IP8000](https://www.aten.com/global/en/products/kvm/kvm-over-ip-switches/ip8000/). There are a few posts on upgrading exiting mainboards and dealing with compatibility/feature/price issues [like this one here](https://forums.servethehome.com/index.php?threads%2Fis-there-a-way-to-add-ipmi-to-a-non-sm-motherboard.8435%2F).

If you're device does provide IPMI and it's not possible to update it an "indirect solution" for example would be to remotely control the power outlet through e.g. via smart home technology. This makes it possible to cut power and turn it back on remotely. To get the computer to boot up again it's possible to use the option "remember power state" in the BIOS or to turn it on via WOL.

**Update:**
As the other answer/comments point out there are also other technologies as well. For example Intel's AMT - Active Management Technology which provides similar functionality. According to Wikipedia it's design was focused on clients not on servers as with IPMI.

[Kamil Maciorowski](https://superuser.com/users/432690/kamil-maciorowski) suggested in the comments to the question to use a VM and restart it via the VM-Management console, which would be my favourite work around as well since it would be a little easier to implement if you don't need to restart the host HW.